# how to count number of filled cells in each column of excel using python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlrd

I have a sheet in Excel which is not structured data as you can see  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKvBi.png) .

I tried using `xlrd` package

```
total_rows=worksheet.nrows
total_cols=worksheet.ncols
```

but this is giving me the maximum row count for a column. But I need filled cell count for each column. Could anyone suggest solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to iterate through every row and check whether the cell is empty or not. You can use this:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('excel.xls')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)

count = 0
for row in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col in sheet.row_values(row):
        if col.strip() != '':
            count += 1
```